# Quarkus Panache MongoDB: Delete only matching data from Array

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Is it possible to delete only filtered elements from an array, using panache with Quarkus?

```
{
    "id": "1234567",
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "Type1",
            "value": "Value1"
        },
        {
            "type": "Type2",
            "value": "Value2"
        },
    ]
}
```

I want delete all elements with `type` equal to `Type2`. I have tried with: `delete("data.type","Type2")`, but it delete the entire document from the db

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, not sure if it is possible.

Supposing `data` is a `List` you can iterate and remove the item `Type2` and then update the entire document.